# Instrumented and JVM/Robolectric Unit Tests in Library module cannot access classes in another module

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, robolectric

Not sure why this is happening in the latest Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5. This type of scenerio has worked in older versions of Android Studio. What is a valid workaround to access artifacts from another library in a library's unit test?

To demonstrate the issue, I have a simple project that consists of two library modules.

1. AbstractFruits
2. ConcreteFruits

The image below shows a simple interface in AbstractFruits

**AbstractFruits->IApple.java**
[image]

For the ConcreteFruits library, I have configured it to be dependent on AbstractFruits

**ConcreteFruits->build.gradle**
[image]

You can see the autocomplete works because IApple.class is a part of the classpath for the source code in ConcreteFruits.

**ConcreteFruits->GrannySmith.java**
[image]

However, when I try to create an instance variable in Android Instrumented path, it does not autocomplete because it cannot see it.

**ConcreteFruits->ApplicationTest.java**
[image]

Also from within a JVM Test, it cannot see IApple from AbstractFruits library either.

**ConcreteFruits->ExampleUnitTest.java**
[image]

Anyone have any idea how to make this work. I do not want to repeat IApple in a project outside of that shared library, AbstractFruits

For reference, here is gradle for the shared abstractfruits library:

**AbstractFruits->build.gradle**
[image]

**UPDATE**
- Works fine via command line, but not IDE

Comment: Did you try to rebuild project? Also, try to delete cache

Comment: Reset cache does not help. Does work with Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: Its already flagged as critical bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201295

Comment: I have the same issue